# 404 error: Resource not available jersey tomcat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, servlets, jersey

I am trying to implement simple "Hello Jersey" program. But its giving me

> 404 error: Resource not available

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
 <display-name>MessageProcessorMyTest</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey MessageProcessor Application</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.wordcount</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
 <param-name>unit:WidgetPU</param-name>
 <param-value>persistence/widget</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey MessageProcessor Application</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

MessageEnd.java:

```
package com.example.wordcount;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


public class MessageEnd {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/send")

public String sayHello(){
    return "Hello Jersey";
}
}
```

I am using jersey 2.11 version
My Context root : message
When I direct to

`http://localhost:8080/message/`

index.html getting displayed

But, when I try to direct

`http://localhost:8080/message/rest/send`

404 Error is coming.

I have included following jersey files in webapp>WEB-INF>lib directory:
[image]

Please guide me.

Comment: Are there any deployment errors in the Tomcat log?

Comment: I just checked my console. I am getting following error:                SEVERE: Exception starting Context with name [/message]

Comment: Perhaps you could add the stacktrace to the question...

Comment: I just added "jersey-common.jar" file to " webapp>WEB-INF>lib" folder and that error is gone.

Comment: I'm glad you've sorted the issue, but according to your screenshot, it was already there.

Comment: Yes.. then I removed after posting this.

Comment: I am able to "Hello Jersey" when I move @Path("/send") above class declaration.

Comment: still wondering why will that affect!

Answer (score 0):

> @Aparna Savant - I am able to "Hello Jersey" when I move
>   @Path("/send") above class declaration. – Aparna Savant Aug 11 '14 at
>   19:10

**Thank you so much for writing this. I wasted almost 20 hours trying to fix my api.**

Below is what I did to fix my code.

Before

```
@RestController
@Path("/api")
public class AuxdboAPIResouce {
```

After

```
@Path("/api")
@RestController    
public class AuxdboAPIResouce {
```